# New items in Gridview added at runtime

Tags: java, android, gridview, runtime, adapter

I have a problem with my shoping list application. I implemented a button adapter from this [tutorial](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/comment-page-1/) which I will use for adding products to list. Each buuton in my gridview will be a product and each product will have context menu where I can add it to list or delete the product.

Problem is that user should have ability to add new products or categories and I don't know how to add items to gridview at runtime. I thought that I could create some dynamic array like list in c++ but i'm new to android and java so I have no idea how to implement something like that.

I tried to implement stack but every time I try to push something app crashes. The same is with array list.

ButtonAdapter :

```
ButtonAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> array){
  mContext = c; 
  arrayInAdapter = array; } 


public int getCount() {  
    int a;
    a = arrayInAdapter.size();
 return a;  
}  

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
 Button btn;  

 if (convertView == null) {  
  //if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes  
  btn = new Button(mContext);  
  btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(130, 130));  
  btn.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);  
 }  
 else {  
 btn = (Button) convertView;  
 }  
 btn.setText(arrayInAdapter.get(position));   
 btn.setTextColor(Color.RED);  
 btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sample_0);  
 btn.setId(position); 
 btn.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(position));

 return btn;  
}
```

}

and in Grid Activity i have another arraylist

```
public static ArrayList<String> arrayInGrid;
```

in onCreate:

```
gridView.setAdapter(new ButtonAdapter(this,arrayInGrid ));
```

but when i try to send new item to array program crashes.

```
arrayInGrid.add("new");
```

In fact it crashes at

```
arrayInAdapter.size();
```

in button adapter.

any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the values in your dynamic array to the BaseAdapter for that GridView.
Here's a tutorial, Hope it will help you.
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

Comment: yes but how should I implement this dynamic array to pass elements to Base Adapter? Can you give me some hint?

Comment: You can achieve this in two ways,
OPTION 1: Create a "public static" array for dynamic values in your main activity and access the array from BaseAdapter class.
OPTION 2: Add an array list argument for your BaseAdapter constructor and pass your array to BaseAdapter when you call this adapter class.
Here, you can change your constructor as,
ButtonAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Type> array){
mContext = c;
arrayInAdapter = array;
}

Comment: OK i changed my code as you suggested but i still have some problems. i updated my question. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: can you post your BaseAdapter class and GridAvctivity here.?